# How does the output of PHP functions work using print_r?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to print the current month in a wordpress page using a plugin.

```
function RSB_Archive_Function( $atts ) {

    $month = date('M');
    $year = date('y');

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );   

    print_r($month);


} 

add_shortcode('rsb-archive', 'RSB_Archive_Function');
```

For some reason, the month 'Mar' is being printed above the header and also in the page when I insert the shortcode into the page? As seen here: http://www.robotspacebrain.com/archive-coding/

Any ideas why this my be happening?

Comment: this has nothing to do with `php` and everything to do with how your content (html) is structured and marked up (css) vs. when this function is called (the `print_r` text is output)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why the output is printed in two different places instead of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shortcode function should return the value, not output it.  Without its second argument, `print_r` outputs the value when it's called.

Try

```
return print_r($month, true);
```

instead.  Though in this case, I don't think the `print_r` is necessary; just return `$month`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I didn't realize that you have to return the print_r value to suppress the output.